# Paragraph type in VBA

Tags: vba, types, ms-word, paragraph

I try to run the following code:

```
Sub Para()
    Dim objParagraph As paragraph
    Set objParagraph = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1)
    objParagraph.Alignment = wdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
End Sub
```

But the compiler gives me back that the custom type is not defined. How is that so? I found this code here: https://bettersolutions.com/word/paragraphs/vba-code.htm

Comment: Which line is the compiler flagging?

Comment: Are you trying to run the code in Word, or in another application such as Excel or Access?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 'wdParagraphAlignment.'

```
Sub Para()
    Dim objParagraph As Paragraph
    Set objParagraph = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1)
    objParagraph.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
End Sub
```